# Use index number to show just a few options in a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a dropdown list that looks like this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Lime</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Can I somehow use the index number to just show the first three options in the dropdown?

```
$("#mySelect").find("OPTION").each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
});
```

Gets me the following output, but I just want the dropdown to show 0, 1 and 2. There is no possibility to modify the list in itself and get rid of 2 options.

```
0: Apple
1: Pineapple
2: Lime
3: Pear
4: Orange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$('#mySelect option').eq(2).nextAll('option').remove();
```

This will remove all the options after 3 options

```js
$('#mySelect option').eq(2).nextAll('option').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Pineapple</option>
<option>Lime</option>
<option>Pear</option>
<option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `hide()` the options you don't want displayed.

Here you can hide every `option` above the index 3 by using the selector `:nth-of-type(n+4)`

```js
$('#mySelect option:nth-of-type(n+4)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Lime</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#mySelect").find("OPTION").each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
    if(index > 2){
      $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Pineapple</option>
<option>Lime</option>
<option>Pear</option>
<option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just hide any beyond index 2

```js
$('#mySelect option:gt(2)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Lime</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below js also working,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#mySelect").children('option:gt(2)').hide();
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Lime</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```